# MySQL stored procedure, do not ever raise error?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I would like to make a Stored procedure in MySQL with an try/catch to prevent the error going to my java project. But since there is no try/catch in MySQL im searching for alternatives.

The only thing i need to prevent, is to dont get a "Duplicate key" error from mysql in my java project. If i get this error, i dont want to show anything and act like it has inserted normal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you catch this error withi your application?

Anyway, from docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued

.